# Premature end of file error in XML Request

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, soap, xmlhttprequest, salesforce

for some reason I am getting this error when trying to create a simple login request to Salesforce.

This works exactly as it should in postman, however, when I try and convert to Google Apps Script it seems to create a "Premature end of file" error.

````
  var myHeaders = {

    "Content-Type": 'text/xml',
    SOAPAction: '/',
    Cookie: "BrowserId=sB-PspOVEeqEttdm-K56tw",


  }



/*myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/xml");
myHeaders.append("SOAPAction", "\"\"");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "BrowserId=sB-PspOVEeqEttdm-K56tw");*/


var raw = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n    <Header>\n    </Header>\n    <Body>\n        <login xmlns=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\">\n            <username>xx@xx.com</username>\n            <password>xx</password>\n        </login>\n    </Body>\n</Envelope>";
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow',
  muteHttpExceptions : true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/48.0/", requestOptions)
  //.then(response => response.text())
  //.then(result => logger.log(result))
  //.catch(error => logger.log('error', error)); 


Logger.log(response.getContentText())```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- I think that in this case, `Cookie: "BrowserId=sB-PspOVEeqEttdm-K56tw"` might not be required.
- The properties of `body` and `redirect` are not included in the arguments of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.

#### Modified script:

```
var myHeaders = {
  SOAPAction: '/',
}
var raw = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n    <Header>\n    </Header>\n    <Body>\n        <login xmlns=\"urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com\">\n            <username>xx@xx.com</username>\n            <password>xx</password>\n        </login>\n    </Body>\n</Envelope>";
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  contentType: "text/xml",
  payload: raw,
  muteHttpExceptions : true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/48.0/", requestOptions);
Logger.log(response.getContentText())
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the values of `SOAPAction`, `raw` and `https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/48.0/` are correct.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)